# Boolean is true in Flash, but false in Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have this function in Flash:

```
public function checkFile(file:String):Boolean{
                var b:Boolean;
                var responder:Responder = new Responder(function(reply:Boolean):void{
                    b=reply;
                    msg("vid_"+file+".flv "+ "exists? " + reply);
                    setState("ready");
                    status = "ready";
                },
                    function(res:Object):void{
                        trace("checkFile call failed");
                    });
                mync.call("checkFile",responder,"vid_"+file);
                return b;
            }
```

I can confirm that the `reply` variable is true, but `return b` ends up false:

This is the javascript I use to call the flash function:

```
function checkFile(){
   alert(thisMovie("vidRecorder").checkFile(currentVid));           
}
```

And that opens up a message box saying `false`, while the flash file displays `true`

What's going on? How can I fix it so that my function returns the same value as `reply`?

Comment: What's going on is an **asynchronous operation**

Comment: @Pointy Oh no! That sounds ominous, especially since you put it in bold. Let me look that up.

Comment: The concept of async and callbacks are very well explained in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the anonymous function in your responder is executed asynchronously.

When your `checkFile()` function returns the value of `b` is still `false`. Eventually, your anonymous function is executed and `b` gets set to `true` ... but it's too late in this case, as your `checkFile()` function has already returned `false`.

To work around this, you might consider doing this in a slightly different fashion:

When your anonymous function is executed, have it call out to javascript with the asynchronous response. Something like this:

```
public function checkFile(file:String):void {
    var responder:Responder = new Responder(function(reply:Boolean):void{
        msg("vid_"+file+".flv "+ "exists? " + reply);
        setState("ready");
        status = "ready";
        ExternalInterface.call('someJavascriptFunction', reply);
    },
    function(res:Object):void{
        trace("checkFile call failed");
    });
    mync.call("checkFile",responder,"vid_"+file);
    // note we no longer return a value here
}
```

In the above code, we call a new Javascript function and provide it the result of the asynchronous operation.